# New "Hardwood" Floor Layout

Tags: flooring, remodeling, engineered-flooring

Redoing a big a portion of the first floor in our 1984 home.
Need some advice on layout of floor planks.
I understand the material we end up choosing will affect layout pattern, but for now we are looking at either engineered hardwood, pergo, or allure planks...
Please reference the diagram and my thoughts for each possible layout. Which layout is best in your opinion?

[image: floorlayout]

**OPTION 1:**

- I like this layout because it will make the hallway seem "long" and "large" since planks are going the length of the longest wall
- Not sure I like how the expanded kitchen area could potentially look "smaller"

**OPTION 2:**

- This option would not be cost effective, but has the potential to look unique and all around pleasant no matter which area you are in.
- Not all floor materials will support this configuration because of plank ends and seams, etc.

**OPTION 3:**

- This will make the expanded Kitchen look "long" and "large"
- Could make the hallway leading into the kitchen seem cramped and narrow.

**OPTION 4:**

- Compromise between Option 1 and Option 3.
- Would require a transition piece at the end of the hallway leading into kitchen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd vote #4 = fewest cuts, least amount of labor, least amount of waste. It's also see as the 'default' as most argue that floors look best when laid in the direction parallel to widest walls.

For real hardwood, the general rule of thumb is to lay it perpendicular to the floor joists. This is to add strength. It probably adds a little strength to laminate flooring, but not sure it's enough to worry about.

But, at the end of the day, it's a personal opinion thing. Go with what you like.

As for the transition piece, you *may* need it, but engineered laminates are pretty stable. They don't expand and contract a whole lot. You might be able to get by with merely leaving a 1/8" gap or so and caulk it with matching caulk.

Comment: Great advice all around.